# Authorization to access resource based on role and record's state

Tags: react-admin

What is the best way to restrict access to resource depend on both the user's permission and the state of the record? For example, form that has some kind of workflow such as timesheet or expense claim system, where user can submit a form and then the form is in *submitted* state where user can only *view* them and only the admin can *edit* the form?

Trying to figure out best way to enforce the permissions based in `AuthProvider` to prevent user to just change the URL browser from switching between "show/edit" mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 possibilities:

1. Set both a `show` and an `edit` view in the Resource. In the `edit` view, if the user permissions don't allow the edition, use [a `<Redirect>` component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) to redirect to the `show` view.
2. Set only an `edit` view that, depending on the permissions, renders a `<SimpleForm>` or a `<SimpleShowLayout>`

Here is how I would go with the second solution:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Edit, useRecordContext, SimpleForm, TextInput, SimpleShowLayout, TextField  } from 'react-admin';

export const PostEdit = ({ permissions, ...props }) => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <EditContent permissions={permissions}/>
    </Edit>
);

const EditContent = ({ permissions }) => {
    const record = useRecordContext();
    if (record?.canEdit && permissions === "admin") {
        return (
            <SimpleForm>
                <TextInput source="title" />
            </SimpleForm>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <SimpleShowLayout>
                <TextField source="title" />
            </SimpleShowLayout>);
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, my implementation was using the option 1 that you mentioned with `useRedirect`. I was hoping there is a way to centralize the logic in `AuthProvider` :-)

Comment: There is no built-in way to handle record-based authorization in react-admin, but you can put the logic inside a new method of your authProvider (say `authProvider.canEdit(record)`, and call it from the `<EditContent>` using the `useAuthProvider` hook.